# How to Handle multiple Async ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I have a Program that makes about 18000 ajax requests but it keep saying :
err_insufficient_resources when using chrome any hints ?

Comment: You can use javascript promises for this.

Comment: Avoid having all of these requests in parallel. Try to paginate your calls and process them in batch with promises (100 at a time for example).

Comment: you mean using the $.when function ?

Comment: @POZ could you please give me a tutorial link as it is my first time to hear about promises

Comment: You can use a library such as jQuery (as @Anil suggested in his answer) or use native JS to chain the promises If you want to read more about this, you can check this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0):

It might help you [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function (a1, a2) {
    //all AJAX requests are finished
});
```

OR

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

Comment: i am using $.when but i use it after a loop which makes all the requests and then the loop is followed by $.when here is my code :

 for(var i=0;i<category.length;i++)//loop to open all the category
 {
  request=$.ajax({url:category[i]});
  sub_requests.push(request);
 }
 $.when.apply(null,sub_requests).done(function(){//processing the calls});